# group array of objects by property first letter

Tags: javascript

im struggling a little with this, been a while since ive coded javascript ... trying to convert this

```
items = {
 "data": [
  {
    "name" : "john"
  },
  {
    "name" : "james"
  },
  {
    "name" : "joe"
  },
  {
    "name" : "brian"
  },
  {
    "name" : "bojan"
  },
  {
    "name" : "billy"
  },
  {
    "name" : "dean"
  },
  {
    "name" : "darren"
  },
  {
  "name" : "doug"
  }
]
}
```

into this format

```
items = {
 "data": [
  {
    letter: "j"
    names : ["john", "james", "joe"]
  },
  {
    letter: "b"
    names : ["brian", "bojan", "billy"]
  },
  {
    letter: "j"
    names : ["dean", "darren", "doug"]
  },
  ]
}
```

I've been trying to do this using reduce but not having much look.... is there a simpler way to to do it?

Comment: _"I've been trying to do this using reduce..."_ - You've missed to post that as well... We will help to fix your script, but for this we need to see it. SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Loop through and create a new json object, this might get you started `var data = items.data;

var newData = [];

for(var i in data)
{
     var name = data[i].name;
     console.log(name); 
}`

Comment: apologies andreas .. youre right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object with the letters as keys from which you can extrapolate the array of objects you need by iterating over the [`object entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const items = {"data":[{"name":"john"},{"name":"james"},{"name":"joe"},{"name":"brian"},{"name":"bojan"},{"name":"billy"},{"name":"dean"},{"name":"darren"},{"name":"doug"}]};

// `reduce` over the data to produce an object
// with letter keys, and array values where the names are added
const obj = items.data.reduce((acc, c) => {
  const letter = c.name[0];
  acc[letter] = (acc[letter] || []).concat(c.name);
  return acc;
}, {})

// `map` over the object entries to return an array of objects
items.data = Object.entries(obj).map(([letter, names]) => {
  return { letter, names }
}).sort((a, b) => a.letter > b.letter);

console.log(items);
```

Comment: thanks Andy, it was the second part i was missing..... i was trying to do it all within reduce and getting myself tied up

Comment: whats the best way to sort by letter?

Answer (score 1):

**Vanilla javascript implementation:**

```js
const items = {
 "data": [
  {
    "name" : "john"
  },
  {
    "name" : "james"
  },
  {
    "name" : "joe"
  },
  {
    "name" : "brian"
  },
  {
    "name" : "bojan"
  },
  {
    "name" : "billy"
  },
  {
    "name" : "dean"
  },
  {
    "name" : "darren"
  },
  {
  "name" : "doug"
  }
]
}

const transformed = {
  data:[]
}

const findByLetter = (letter) => (element) => element.letter === letter; 



for(let i = 0; i < items.data.length; i++){

  const letter = items.data[i].name.split("")[0];
  const elIndex = transformed.data.findIndex(findByLetter(letter));
  if(elIndex > -1){

 transformed.data[elIndex].names.push(items.data[i].name);
  }else{
   
  transformed.data.push({
    letter,
    names: [items.data[i].name],
  });
  }
  
};

console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const items = {"data":[{"name":"john"},{"name":"james"},{"name":"joe"},{"name":"brian"},{"name":"bojan"},{"name":"billy"},{"name":"dean"},{"name":"darren"},{"name":"doug"}]};

let res = items.data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let l = item.name[0];
    if (acc.data.filter(e => e.letter == l)[0] === undefined) acc.data.push({'letter': l, names: [] });
    acc.data.filter(e => e.letter == l)[0].names.push(item.name);
    return acc;
}, {"data": []})

console.log(res)
```